# trigger('click') not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running following piece of code in Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.add-photo',function() {


$("#images").append($('<input/>').attr('type', 'file').attr('name','uploads[]').attr('class', 'photo-upload-box').attr('value', '').trigger('click'));


});
});
</script>
```

HTML coding

```
<input type="submit" class="add-photo">
<div id="images"> </div>
```

As we know this will create new input for file each time when the function executes. What I am facing is the click event is not working in IE but working fine in firefox.

I also tried trigger('click') but it is not working in IE. Can anybody suggest how can I make it working in Internet Explorer?

Comment: try to provide a functional example.. so we can help you easier

Comment: @Saptal, would you please show the sample coding please ?

Comment: Are you saying the click for `.add-photo` isn't working or the `.click()` on the file input?

Comment: Please define "_not working_".

Comment: Edited the question by adding more information...

Comment: What does "_not working_" mean? The code inserts an input to a wrong place? It doesn't insert an input at all? It drinks all your booze?

Comment: Yea thats sounds fine , But I thought , you can track it down by running above code in IE and Firefox and can find what is "NOT WORKING" , simply it need to be open the window for selecting the image files, that is getting in firefox but not IE

Comment: triggering .click won't work in IE for file inputs. You'll have to instead use css trickery to hide an input over your button. Detailed in the duplicate.

Comment: sorry it is extremely meaning less and Iam not getting anything from the duplicates you posted ?? Can you please post the answer here

Comment: You are not clearly reading and executing what Iam asking is , instead some are interested in putting downvote to my question rather than understanding :( thinking it is time wasting , crap

Comment: it isn't possible to do what you are asking. you have to use a workaround.

Comment: Kevin , is it the work around you are suggesting http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html , I just need to work / execute the click function on file box only after it get appended

Comment: you can't do it only after it is appended. It has to already exist so that it can be infront of the button.

Comment: You people are not cleary mentioning where or what function is failing to execute in IE and you are suggestions are not seeing valubale instead degrading some one who have doubts, hated and curse this rules offenses

Comment: calling .click on an input element of type "file" will not open the open file dialog in IE. i don't know how i can be any more clear than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134732/discussion-between-tom-and-kevin-b).

Comment: This is fixed myself !! Just added ID and find the count and applied logic and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had some formatting issues in the creation of your input element. This should work for you. Simply use the native onclick also to call the function as you don't really need a jquery watcher for that. Let me know if you need any more help :-)

The edited version will now apply to anything with the class `.add-photo`.

```js
$('body').on('click','.add-photo',function(){
  
  let input = $("<input>",{
    'type': 'file',
    'name': 'uploads[]',
    'class': 'photo-upload-box'
  });
  
  $( input ).click();
  
  $( input ).change(function(){
  
    console.log( this.value );
  
  });
  
});
```

```css
.add-photo {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="add-photo">Add photo</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote... it is exactly what was requested by the OP...

Comment: because you suggested using onclick attribute and a global function. it'l work, but...

Comment: @KevinB Can you please explain why my solution is improper? Seems to me that the op was asking for a working solution. But i will certainly edit the post to have a global watcher if it pleases you...

Comment: since you're creating an element, you could just as well bind an event directly to it. Right in the creating part.

Comment: @KevinB I understand that and while I feel that we may disagree on the implementation i don't think that either of us are right or wrong. I edited the correction with an event binder per your suggestion.

Comment: the other reason is... i don't think this is going to solve the problem anyway. I'll find the dupe in a few min

Comment: @KevinB This is completely functional does not create duplicate elements and will respond to a user actually selecting a file. If this does not solve the problem I am not certain what will...

Comment: @Lucas Thanks for giving an answer, but I resolved it myself by thinking and applying my own logic. Don't worry about down rates, that is normal here even if we ask accurate questions. They will down rate if they don't know the answer.